# unable to boot ubuntu after refreshing windows 8

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader

Ubuntu was installed in disk H and windows 8 in disk C. Now, I refreshed windows 8 and I am not able to get the option to boot to ubuntu when I start my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

As I am not able to comment because of less reputations I am commenting here.
In Windows 8 there are 2 types of boot from which Secure boot is responsible for starting Windows 8 (by default). Go to BIOS settings and disable Secure boot, then Restart .You will get an option now. If still not working change the priority of boot from BIOS settings and keep it Ubuntu by default.
If still it does not work comment here.